How to calculate the relative speed when three bodies are involved?
Two trains A and B start from a station and move in parallel tracks with velocities 40 kmph and 60 kmph respectively. A man sitting in train A. watches a lady who walks inside the train B at a speed of 5 kmph opposite to the train's movement. What is the velocity of the lady according to the man?
I asked this to a few people, some say its 25kmph while others say its 15kmph. Could anyone please help?

15, because the speed of the lady is 55 kmph.

Just draw a principal vector diagram of separate movements :

Add $\vec B + \vec C = \vec C~'$ and you will get woman velocity relative to the ground. Now subtract that from train's A velocity vector and you will find woman relative velocity to the man, $\vec C~'-\vec A = \vec C~'_{man}$
